# Python curses, macOS, PyСharm: could not find terminal

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pycharm, curses

Есть следующий код:

```
import curses


def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getkey()


curses.wrapper(main)
```

При запуске кода возникает ошибка в окне "Run":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arkamn/PycharmProjects/pseudo/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    curses.wrapper(main)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/curses/__init__.py", line 84, in wrapper
    stdscr = initscr()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/curses/__init__.py", line 29, in initscr
    setupterm(term=_os.environ.get("TERM", "unknown"),
_curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminal
```

Проверяю переменные окружения в окне "Terminal":

```
(venv) [~/PycharmProjects/pseudo]$ echo $TERM     
xterm-256color
(venv) [~/PycharmProjects/pseudo]$ echo $TERMINFO 
/usr/share/terminfo/78
```

При добавлении переменных окружения в конфиг PyСharm
[image: pyCharm env variables]
происходит следующая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/curses/__init__.py", line 89, in wrapper
    cbreak()
_curses.error: cbreak() returned ERR

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arkamn/PycharmProjects/pseudo/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    curses.wrapper(main)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/curses/__init__.py", line 111, in wrapper
    nocbreak()
_curses.error: nocbreak() returned ERR
```

Причем данный код корректно отрабатывает в отдельном терминале (напрмер iTerm2) или в закладке "Terminal" в PyСharm.

Решение нужно для запуска pyCharm Debug.

Comment: Подозреваю, что решение вашей проблемы заключается в той галочке, которую вы тактично обрезали на скриншоте сразу под надписью "Execution"

Comment: Установил Emulate terminal in output console и похоже это помогло. Добавил строчку stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "Hello") для вывода текста на экран, но процесс просто завершается с кодом 0. Дебагер теперь запускается, но кнопки шагов не активны.